# Javascript working on online server not working on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

The code must to finde all the checkedboxes and delete all...
When in localhost (XAMPP) I select some of the checkboxes and after i press "Delete All" it show me next page:

[image: Errors Screenshot]

BUT the code are working and delete the selected checkbox.

Checkbox code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="CB<?=++$chkCount?>" name="CB<?=$chkCount?>" value="<?=$row['id'];?>" />
```

Function code:

```
            case 'deleteAll':
            for($i=1; $i<=$totalRows; $i++){
                if((bool)($_POST['cb'.$i]) == TRUE){
                    $id = $_POST['cb'.$i];
                    $delRec = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_print WHERE id = '".$id."'"));

                    mysql_query("DELETE FROM tbl_print WHERE id=".$id) or die(mysql_error());
                }
            }
        break;
```

Comment: It looks like you're accessing the `POST` value in php as `$_POST['cb'.$i]` (lowercase) and assigning the name in the input field as `CB` (uppercase). PHP is case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Matt O'Connell you should use `$_POST['CB'.$i]` instead of `$_POST['cb'.$i]` to match the case of the variable you set in your html form.

Your function should be:

```
case 'deleteAll':
    for($i=1; $i<=$totalRows; $i++){
        if((bool)($_POST['CB'.$i]) == TRUE){
            $id = $_POST['CB'.$i];
            $delRec = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_print WHERE id = '".$id."'"));

            mysql_query("DELETE FROM tbl_print WHERE id=".$id) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
break;
```

Comment: I did that and still is page is showing the image i upload.

Like I said, the code is working but showing that images.

Answer (score 0):

also use `name="CB[]"` and use `foreach` to get value